# What's the correct implication between $\forall x(\,P(x) \vee Q(x)\,)$ and $\forall xP(x) \vee ∀xQ(x)$?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have two statements:

$$P_1= \forall x(\;P(x) \vee Q(x)\;)$$

$$P_2= \forall xP(x) \vee ∀xQ(x)$$

I would like to ask about correct implication between those statements. I know the difference between those statements but I have problem to choose correct implication.

Comment: What a shame that a new contributor has written a good question, while also taking the effort to write a proper question (MathJax notation included, which is quite rare), and still people keep downvoting

Comment: Try with a simple interpretation : "Every natural number is (either Even or Odd)" versus "Either (every natural number is Even) or (every natural number is Odd)".

Answer (score 0):

$P2$ implies $P1$ (quite easy to prove): Given $x$ and assuming $P2$ is true, then either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ is true. In both scenarios, $P1$ is also true

The converse is not true, though. For instance, if $x$ can be any real number:

Let $P(x)=[x \geq 0]$

Let $Q(x)=[x \leq 0]$

You can see that $P1$ is true but $P2$ is not.

Comment: so u mean P2 => P1 ? I don't think so

Comment: I think it does (see my proof)!